# Splitting List with Racket

Tags: racket

Given a list, and a number, n, I am trying to split a list into two separate lists: one into a list of length n, and the second list being the rest of the original list.

Here is what I have:

```
(define (part lst i)
(if (> i 0)
(list (append (list (first lst)) (list (part (rest lst) (- i 1)))))
(append lst)))
```

Where lst is the inputted list, and i is the number. When I input the list '(1 2 3 4) with the number 2, I return an output of: '((1 ((2 (3 4))))) instead of what I want which is '((1 2) (3 4)).

This is for a homework assignment, so it would be much appreciated if someone could just point me in the right direction as to where my problem lies, and because it is a hw assignment, I only am allowed to use the simple racket functions.

EDIT:

When I change the code to:

```
(define (part lst i)
(if (> i 0)
(append (list (first lst)) (list (part (rest lst) (- i 1))))
(append lst)))
```

I get an output of '(1 (2 (3 4))).

Comment: You really have to go down to basics and learn about `cons` and how pairs are chained together to become lists since the line where you use `append` and `list` and `list` of a `list` (you might expect `rest` to reurn a list) seems like you need to [read some more](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65355-scheme-lists/) and you need to stop using `list` and `append` completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using existing libraries**

There's an easy way to solve this problem in Racket, just use the built-in [`split-at`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._split-at%29%29) procedure (also available in the [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#split-at) library). This has the advantage of making a single pass across the input list:

```
(define (part lst i)
  (let-values (((head tail) (split-at lst i)))
    (list head tail)))
```

Another option would be to use Racket's built-in procedures [`take`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._take%29%29) and [`drop`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._drop%29%29) (also available in SRFI-1) - but this will make two passes across the input list:

```
(define (part lst i)
  (list (take lst i)
        (drop lst i)))
```

**Implementation from scratch**

To build our own solution, we could write a procedure that makes a single pass, like this:

```
(define (part lst i)
  (if (negative? i)
      (error "index can't be negative")
      (let loop ((lst lst) (acc '()) (i i))
        (cond ((and (empty? lst) (positive? i))
               (error "index is too large for list"))
              ((zero? i)
               (list (reverse acc) lst))
              (else
               (loop (rest lst) (cons (first lst) acc) (sub1 i)))))))
```

Also, we could implement our own versions of `take` and `drop` - again, this will traverse the input list twice:

```
(define (my-take lst i)
  (if (> i 0)
      (cons (first lst)
            (my-take (rest lst) (- i 1)))
      '()))

(define (my-drop lst i)
  (if (> i 0)
      (my-drop (rest lst) (- i 1))
      lst))

(define (part lst i)
  (list (my-take lst i)
        (my-drop lst i)))
```

Comment: Being homework, the point is to *implement* these functions from basic operations, not use pre-existing versions.

Comment: @AndrewMedico mmm, I was getting to that. Don't rush the downvotes!

Comment: Then don't submit your answer until you've finished writing it. Votes get cast based on what's actually visible at the time, not what might appear later.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Too bad you can't downvote comments, but I disagree.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Racket (and SRFI 1) provide `split-at`, which return the results of `take` and `drop` as multiple values, but using one iteration only. I'm sure the OP's question can also be implemented using one iteration.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I expanded my answer with your suggestions. So many options!